# Bash: run an executable file in background

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an executable file that contains a long loop, so I want to run it in background, how do I do that with bash script in Linux?

I know one way is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + z, then I type `bg`, how to simulate these key pressing in bash script?

Comment: Put an & at the end of calling your script on the console

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103731/67817 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104821/67817

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any executable in linux can be run in the background as follows:

```
 $ ./yourExecutable.exe&
```

Add the `&` character at end. (Assuming `yourExecutable.exe` is in the current working directory)

### How to kill it later on?

```
$ ps -ax | grep yourExecutable.exe
```

You will get an output like:

```
9384  pts/7    S+     0:00 grep yourExecutable.exe
25082 pts/7    T      0:00 yourExecutable.exe&
```

Kill the second process using `SIGKILL`. That is the one you executed in the background.

```
$ kill -9 25082
```

Comment: Thank you. How to stop this background running processing then?

Comment: @rudimeier. I never looked deep into it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @rudimeier `$$` is the *current* process `$!` is the last spawned background pocess. That's a dangerous mistake to make.

Comment: About "How to kill it later": No need for grepping process list. ```"$!"``` is the pid of last background process. ```kill $!```. BTW ```jobs``` lists all background processes. See also ```kill %1``` and ```fg %1```. It's documented in ```man bash```, topic "JOB CONTROL".